# Sort numbers After letters in ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by

Hello i am trying to order by in mysql by sorting

- Special characters
- Letters
- then Numbers

it seems like mysql sorts by

- Special Characters
- Numbers
- then Letters

See below

```
select distinct uag_linecode from part order by uag_linecode;

| A-1          |
| A/C          |
| A1S          |  out of place
| ABP          |
| ABS          |
| ACI          |
| ADM          |
| ADR          |
| BAS          |
```

This is what i want:

```
A-1 
A/C
ABR
ABS
ACI
ADM
ADR 
A1S correct spot
BAS
```

If anyone can help me out i would be eternally grateful.

All the line codes are always 3 characters long.

Comment: Are the codes always 3 characters long?

Comment: Sorting is based on the character code, and those special characters have codes of smaller values than numbers and alphabets.

Comment: That's ASCII et al for you, numbers are first in the table - you will need a custom sort function.

Comment: yes they are always 3 characters long

Comment: Example question on UDF for sorting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339338/mysql-creating-a-user-defined-function-for-a-custom-sort  ofcourse, UDFs are not necessarily of any use to people who do not have sufficient access to the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this would work if it were always the 2nd character -- you might be able to add to the case clause to check for 1st and 3rd characters...

```
select distinct uag_linecode,
substring(uag_linecode, 2, 1)
from part
order by 
  case 
    when substring(uag_linecode, 2, 1) REGEXP ('^[0-9]') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END , uag_linecode
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09afe/7).

--EDIT 
This appears to work for 1st and 3rd characters as well:

```
select distinct uag_linecode,
   substring(uag_linecode, 1, 1),
   substring(uag_linecode, 2, 1),
   substring(uag_linecode, 3, 1)
from part
order by 
   case when substring(uag_linecode, 1, 1) REGEXP ('^[0-9]') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
   substring(uag_linecode, 1, 1),
   case when substring(uag_linecode, 2, 1) REGEXP ('^[0-9]') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
   substring(uag_linecode, 2, 1),
   case when substring(uag_linecode, 3, 1) REGEXP ('^[0-9]') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ,    
   substring(uag_linecode, 3, 1)
```

And more [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71100/3).

Also as @Orbling correctly says, you'll get a better performance (especially if you have lots of records) to remove the REDEXP and use >= '0' AND <= '9'.

Good luck.

Comment: The issue with this is if http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8b91/1 take a look if you add a linecode of BBA it will put the A1S below the BBA it still needs to be in alphabetic order.

Comment: Good answer, though I imagine it will run slow as all hell.  Could just use `... >= '0' && ... <= '9'` to remove the slow `REGEXP` op.

Comment: @user1863457 -- did you see my edits?  Should work with that?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8b91/2

Comment: i just made a edit as well at the top to verify what i mean what you did wouldn't work even though i very much appreciate the help

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71100/1 if u add another letter in the beginning it still needs to go A## then B##, C## etc

Comment: Needed to add more criteria to the ORDER BY: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71100/3 -- I'll edit my answer -- good catch.