# How to sort Mysql data (f21.1,f23)

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I'm pulling data from mysql to a php script
I need to sort some specific data in a certain way, my data are as follows:

- f102
- f101.1
- f21.1
- f24
- f203

I need it to sort this way

- f21.1
- f23
- f101.1
- f102
- f203

I've tried a number of different things but i can't seem to get past the whole "." thing, ignoring the "f" would also be okay since i just need it to sort numerically.

My SQL is: `"SELECT navn FROM grupper ORDER BY navn"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is your solution

```
SELECT navn
 FROM
grupper
 ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(navn,2) AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

**Here is the steps :**

> **Step 1 :** Select your desired field `navn`
>   **Step 2 :** Select `SUBSTRING` without char `f` from string `navn`
>   **Step 3 :** Convert `SUBSTRING` to `UNSIGNED INT` 
>   **Step 4 :** ORDER BY `UNSIGNED int` ASC or DESC as your need

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Mysql's order can be a bit tricky sometimes and the logic behind it might not always be what you expect. In This case, it treats the whole field as a string and not as a complex type.

To do complex sorting or sorting where the value is mixed (eg like yours, text + float) you have to create a custom function.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339338/mysql-creating-a-user-defined-function-for-a-custom-sort) has the answers on how to do that.